# wcout problems on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, unicode, char

I am trying to do some simple box drawing in the terminal using unicode characters. However I noticed that wcout wouldn't output anything for the box drawing characters, not even a place holder. So I decided to write the program below and find out which unicode characters were supported and found that wcout refused to output anything above 255. Is there something i have to do to make wcout work properly? Why can't access any of the extended unicode characters?

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (wchar_t c = 0; c < 0xFFFF; c++)
    {
        cout << "Iteration " << (int)c << endl;
        wcout << c << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't recommend using `wcout` because it is non-portable, inefficient (always performs transcoding) and doesn't support all of Unicode (e.g. surrogate pairs).

Instead you can use [the open-source {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) to portably print Unicode text including [box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing_(Unicode_block)), for example:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print("┌────────────────────┐\n"
             "│   Hello, world!    │\n"
             "└────────────────────┘\n");
}
```

prints (https://godbolt.org/z/4EP6Yo):

```
┌────────────────────┐
│   Hello, world!    │
└────────────────────┘
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt}.